# Shared Link URL Redirection in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, redirect

We are on SharePoint Online and have several documents that link to documents in a SharePoint Document Library.

One person would like to redirect one of the shared links from the Document Library to point to a website.  IE: a document that is in the Document Library is shared from there using the 'Share' ability.  He would like to make the link now re-direct to a website instead of the document in question.

Is there a way to do that?

(Edited)

To clarify, as some of the answers here seem to misunderstand the intention:

We have documents in SharePoint Online that are shared as links to SharePoint (IE: https://.sharepoint.com/:i:/s// which points to the document in question there).

We then have documents and webpages that reference that document via that shared link.

What the user wants is to use that Shared Link, and redirect it to a website link.

Comment: Are you trying to create a "new" link with redirection or trying to change the "existing shared link" of document/file to work as redirection link?

Comment: The basic jist is that we have several documents that have 'existing' links in SharePoint Online.  Instead of trying to find the documents and fix that particular link, the idea is to have that Document Link redirect to a different URL.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: no, it's not possible to update a link inside a PDF or a Word document hosed on a SharePoint library.**

Original answer:

On a **SharePoint document library > +New** you can create a `Link`. A link is in fact a text file with two lines:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/123456789-abcdef-12345678?e=ABCED
```

Out of the box, there is no way to change the URL. You can only rename the link. But, you can download the `.link` file, open it with a text editor (NotePad, VS Code, etc.), change the URL, and upload it back to the library. It's not 100% reliable but it could work.

[image: new link]
[image: create a link]
[image: download link]
[image: edit link]
[image: replace link]

Comment: So, I don't think this will work with the intention I am looking for.

Let me point out what we are trying to go for here.

We have PDFs that are shared from SharePoint Online.  We have other documents that reference those links.

What we want to do, on SharePoint Online, is use those existing links, to go to a Website instead of the Document on SharePoint Online.

The impression I am getting that this is not possible, that the documents that uses the Shared Link should be updated to go to the appropriate URL instead of trying to make the SharePoint Share Link redirected.

Comment: Again, I am am of the opinion of updating the document, the user, on the other hand, wants the existing share link that is going to the Document (Not a URL link, an actual PDF/Word/Excel Document) to be redirected to a Website.

Comment: It's better if you edit your original question, because your comment does not describe the same requirement.